# How to redirect an old YouTube video to an updated version?

Tags: youtube, video

I made a few tweaks to a video, and I'd prefer people to go to that one, instead of the old one. I understand that I can't replace the video, I have to add the new one, but I'm going round in circles trying to work out how to point the old ones to the new place.

Various tutorials, stack exchange answers, Google / Youtube 'help' files suggest the following:

Use annotations (but they are no longer available)

Use cards - but I can't find out how, and it looks to me like they are not available on my interface either. The official advice video on Cards (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6140493) says to go to the Creator Studio, but that's not on my dropdown menu, and I can't find cards anywhere in my youtube account.

All my searches seem to point me to completely outdated options. Please, somebody - help!

At this point, I'm ready to just delete the old videos and be done with it, so this is my last ditch attempt to find a solution that surely plenty of people would be interested in...

Answer (score 1):

You can not replace the video, but you might be able to annotate the video and point to the new video. Also, change your description to the new YouTube video. The other option is to delete the video and create the new video. Then with any web sites you own, you can replace your content with the new URL. Sorry, there is not a good way to redirect to a new video.